# Uploading file to a remote folder from php script

Tags: php, linux

I know there are previous questions with almost same title as mine, but please check my details before marking it as duplicate. 
I want to upload a file from a PHP script on my local machine to another machine on thesame LAN. Even though I could ping the remote system IP address, when I try to upload the file, I get an error indicating that my file could not be moved to final location on the remote server. Below is the script that does not work: It threw up the error: **ERROR: File not uploaded. Try again.**

```
    $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "//10.32.0.17/home/uploads/$log_username/$db_file_name");
        // Check to make sure the move result is true before continuing
        if($moveResult != true){
                echo "ERROR: File not uploaded. Try again.";
                unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
                exit();
}
```

But when I changed the file path to a folder on my local machine like this:

```
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "/home/uploads/$log_username/$db_file_name");
```

It works!

Please, how should I indicate the path to the remote folder? The remote machine is a Linux system while my local machine is a Windows system.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a path to remote machine. Paths are always local.
If they are on the same network though, you can use [samba](https://www.samba.org/samba/).

How about if you used php's [ftp()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) function?

Comment: Okay, I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on your setup, you may also find the rsync utility useful (if you are running linux machines)